# Trying to get property 'photo' of non-object

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

When I implemented the create view it worked fine, but after implementing the show view it stopped working throwing the following error:

Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
Trying to get property 'foto' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\alme\resources\views\aluminio\show.blade.php)
http://127.0.0.1:8000/aluminio/create

**AluminioController.php**

```
    {
        $productos = Aluminio::all();
        return view('aluminio.index',compact("productos"));
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        $productos =Aluminio::find($id);
        return view('aluminio.show', compact('productos'));
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('aluminio.create');
    }

    public function store(Request $request){

        $productos = $request->all();

        if($request->hasFile('foto')){
            $productos['foto']=$request->file('foto')->store('uploads','public');
        }        
        Aluminio::create($productos);

        return redirect(route('aluminio'));
    }
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('aluminio', 'AluminioController@index')->name('aluminio');
Route::get('aluminio/{id}', 'AluminioController@show')->name('aluminio.show');
Route::get('aluminio/create', 'AluminioController@create')->name('aluminio.create');
Route::post('aluminio', 'AluminioController@store')->name('aluminio.store');
```

**create.blade.php**

```
@section('contenido')
            <div class="content-fluid">

                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <form action="{{ route("aluminio.store") }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                  @csrf
                      <div class="col-10">
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label  for="tipologia" class="control-label">Tipología</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tipologia" id="tipologia">
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                          <label  for="caracteristicas" class="control-label">Características</label><br>                            
                          <textarea name="caracteristicas" id="caracteristicas" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                          <label  for="foto" class="control-label">Foto</label>                           
                          <input type="file" class="form-control" name="foto" id="foto">
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Crear</button>
                         </div>
                      </div>                       
                    </form>                 
                </div>
            </div>
            @endsection
```

**show.blade.php**

```
@section('contenido')
            <div class="content-fluid">

                <div class="jumbotron">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <img src="{{ asset('storage').'/'.$productos->foto }}" class="card-img-top" width="100" height="300" alt="...">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <h1 class="display-4">{{ $productos->tipologia }}</h1>
                            <hr class="my-4">
                            <p class="lead">{{ $productos->caracteristicas}}</p>                        
                            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="{{ route('aluminio') }}" role="button">Atras</a>

                        </div>
                    </div>


                  </div>
            </div>
            @endsection
```

Comment: Does the ID really exist? Try `$productos = Aluminio::findOrFail($id)` instead to fetch the model.

Comment: Most probably you succeeded to store image file but.... check if the file name is stored in DB.

Comment: Check your table,  I am sure your photo is not stored currectly. Store your photo name,  you cant store a file in table (without bolb data)

Comment: the images are saved correctly in the database, the show view works correctly it shows all the data with the image, but when I am going to create a new product it is that it gives me the error that, which is what I do not understand if I am in the view create because it gives me a show view error

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here

```
<img src="{{ asset('storage').'/'.$productos->foto }}" class="card-img-top" width="100" height="300" alt="...">
```

to escape the error 
in show method

```
$productos =Aluminio::findOrFail($id);
```

that will return an abort page

> that cause of there's no prodctos and you trying to get property of
>   something didn't exists.

Comment: modifying the method as you suggested tells me that the page cannot find it, I do not understand if I am accessing the create view and the display view works correctly

Comment: that means the id you passed is not exists in db , check it in db.